# pandas groupby transform behaving differently with seemingly equivalent representations

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['a', 'a'], B=[0, 1]))
```

I expected the following two formulations to be equivalent.

***formulation 1***

```
df.groupby('A').transform(np.mean)
```

[image]

***formulation 2***

```
df.groupby('A').transform(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

[image]

I'd consider the results from ***formulation 2*** incorrect.  But before I go crying *bug* maybe someone has a rational explanation for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me:

```
In [19]: df.groupby('A').transform(lambda x: x.sum())
Out[19]:
   B
0  1
1  1

In [20]: df.groupby('A').transform(lambda x: len(x))
Out[20]:
   B
0  2
1  2

In [21]: df.groupby('A').transform(lambda x: x.sum()/len(x))
Out[21]:
   B
0  0
1  0
```

PS Pandas version: 0.19.0

Comment: are you using 0.19?

Comment: I just tested in on 0.19 and 0.18.1 with same results

Comment: @piRSquared, i might be wrong but it could be result of [this downcasting](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2831)